# Submit POST data when user logged in using forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, post, forms-authentication

I have asp.net application that use forms authentication to control access. Let's imagine we have file page.aspx with form in it. When I press search ( submit button in the form) then POST data is sent to that script and I get search results. However if user logged out, then pressed back button in browser and then pressed search, user is redirected to login page. After login,I get that page, but no POST data is sent to that page. Is there any easy way to fix that!

Comment: Please provide more details and any relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST data cannot be sent when redirecting with HTTP redirect response.
So you have to change the flow of the application do detect that the user is logged out ealier:

- Check login status with ajax request before submitting form
- Store submited data in cookie to recreate the POST after logging in
- Store submitted data in session before redirecting to login page

Comment: Thank you, that's nice idea. I thought it could be changed within FormsAuthentication.

Comment: Probably you could write some kind of extension yourself. If you could execute your code when the decision is made to redirect to login page you could store the entire POST data in session or cookie, after logging in check if there is POST information in session/cookie and execute javascript to repeat the POST

Answer (score 1):

The forms authentication cookie is not the session cookie so if you still have your user session you might be able to store the search parameters in your user session and reload them after login.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but as I have many pages that are sending POST, I am aware that is impractical.